# teechart lable is not showing

Tags: vb.net, teechart

i am using steema.teeChart component in our application to generate reports.
i am drowing a line from the left to the rigth and on the rigth side we have a lable with text like: E7, B8, ext... per line

The problem is: 
When the lines are close to each other the text/line name is not showing in the repport.
[image]
in the image you can see 3 lines. the poroblem is that the line name of the top line is not visible.

Here is an example when it is ok:

[image]

Here is the code i am using,

Any advice will be appreciated

```
Dim mrk As Styles.Points
mrk = Me.addMark(Color.Transparent, " ")
mrk.Marks.Visible = False
mrk.Marks.Transparent = True
mrk.VertAxis = Styles.VerticalAxis.Both
mrk.UseAxis = True

mrk.Add(maxX, CSng(drw!afn_x), drw!afn_label.ToString)

Private Function addMark(ByVal color As Color, ByVal oms As String) As Styles.Points
    Dim lpt As New Styles.Points
    chart.Series.Add(lpt)
    lpt.ShowInLegend = False
    lpt.Marks.Visible = True
    lpt.Marks.Transparent = True
    lpt.Marks.Color = color
    lpt.Marks.Style = Styles.MarksStyles.Label
    lpt.Marks.Text = oms
    lpt.Marks.ArrowLength = -8
    lpt.Marks.Arrow.Visible = False
    lpt.Pointer.Visible = False
    lpt.LinePen.Visible = False
    lpt.Color = color.Transparent
    lpt.Pointer.Color = lpt.Color
    lpt.LinePen.Color = lpt.Color
    lpt.UseAxis = False
    lpt.Title = ""
    Return lpt
End Function
```

Comment: I'm not sure about which is your exact problem here. Could you please provide more detailed information accompanied with a [Short, Self Contained, Correct/Compilable, Example](http://www.sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

This is to prevent label overlapping. Automatic labels are not plotted if they'd overlap. You can overcome this issue using custom labels. You'll find an example at *All Features\Welcome !\Axes\Labels\Custom labels* in the features demo at TeeChart's program group. For example:

```
  tChart1.Axes.Left.Labels.Items.Clear();

  (tChart1.Axes.Left.Labels.Items.Add(123,"Hello")).Font.Size=16;
  (tChart1.Axes.Left.Labels.Items.Add(466,"Good\n\rbye")).Transparent=false;
  tChart1.Axes.Left.Labels.Items.Add(300);
  AxisLabelItem a = tChart1.Axes.Left.Labels.Items.Add(-100);
  a.Transparent=false;
  a.Color=Color.Blue;
  a.Transparency=50;
```

If this doesn't help please send us a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://www.sscce.org/). You can post your files [here](http://www.steema.net/upload/).